# Eclipse title bar not showing ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt, titlebar

I know it sounds weird question but I know eclipse title bar shows ADT at the end of project name. But in my case it is not. Also there is not display icon for eclipse in title bar it is just like blank cmd icon.

There is just "java -" I think it should be "Java - ADT"

Answer (score 0):

Reopen the eclipse and choose a different working directory then everything works fine, If you have any important working set of files left in old working directory then import them to current workspace using File>import